# Grid created at runtime, does not render correctly after being tombstoned - reactivated

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

I have a requirement in my application where I need to show a Grid that each time might have different number of rows/columns so I'm creating it programmatically.

While my Grid might look like the following:

[image]

When it is reactivated after being tombstoned for some reason, it does not render as it should. I'm saving the page's state before tombstoning on `OnNavigatedFrom()` and reconstructing the Grid and loading the state on `OnNavigatedTo()`. But my Grid now looks like the following:

[image]

Anyone knows whats going on and how I can fix this?

Comment: **Don't create or manipulate UI elements in procedural code in XAML-based technologies**. Use an `ItemsControl` and a regular Grid or UniformGrid, or see Rachel's [GridHelper](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/wpf-grids-rowcolumn-count-properties/)

Comment: Well, although my pictures show empty grid cells, in reality my cells **might** contain content. I have no idea how I would do that decleratively and how I would bind each cell's datacontext.

Comment: See [ItemsControl](http://drwpf.com/blog/itemscontrol-a-to-z/)

Comment: Did you tried to call Measure(..), Arrange(..) and UpdateLayout() on restore?

Comment: @crea7or I did on `OnNavigatedTo()` but it's not working. 
@HighCore Great read as I have little experience with xaml!  I'll try to implement it with an ItemsControl, possibly with a Selector as I need to use the IsSelected property for my Items. The ItemsPanel would be a Grid and I would bind the Grid.Row and Grid.Column properties in the ItemsContainerStyle for each item. I'll come back with more questions :)